# Interpretation of correlation (coefficient)

Tags: probability, random-variables, finance, correlation

In an discussion we were confronted with a very special opinion about correlation in respect of financial assets.

The widely used correlation coefficient is used here to give an idea about how different assets were behaving in the past.

So one came up with the following interpretation:

```
Correlation coefficient --> Percentage of times the two assets behave in the same way:
+1.00 --> 100%
+0.99 --> 90%
+0.93 --> 80%
+0.79 --> 70%
+0.49 --> 60%
+0.00 --> 50%
-0.49 --> 40%
-0.79 --> 30%
-0.93 --> 20%
-0.99 --> 10%
-1.00 --> 0%
```

Which, in my opinion, is plain wrong. As far as I remember, an correlation of 0.00 has the meaning "One cannot tell how Asset b will behave in respect of the development of Asset a". Especially the probabilty of "Asset b will not do any significant move" is missing in a 50% chance.

What is the meaning of a "0.00" correlation? How can negative correlation coefficients be interpreted? Is an percentage of times a good way of doing that?

edit:

He used the vectors

```
a   b
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   5
8   4
9   3
10  2
11  1
```

To calculate those values in excel, leveraging the correl() function.

Comment: Could you let me know how he derived the percentages at different values of the coefficient.  It is very interesting and I would like to know!!.  Then probably one can dissect that and see if it sounds and conveys the meaning as you have suggested.

Comment: @satishramanathan I will try to find out and add to the question

Comment: @satishramanathan Please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced what your friend has done.  You are right that it is plain wrong.  In the image I have given a counterexample of the choice of b values for 50% correct scenario and have illustrated to you that that correlation is not 0 depending on the choice of the values that your b takes for those that do not move the same way.  To be polite, the calculation of percentages are utterly wrong and depend on the choice of values b takes to relate that percentage to correlation.  Go back to your friend and show him the counterexample.  Good luck  @Graham Kemp has given you the right explanation

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Proof through counterexample is the most intuitive way.

Comment: But as long as the factor is constant, the correlation will be 0?

Comment: what do you mean by " as long as the factor is constant"?  You mean  the values that b vector takes?

Comment: Yes, I made an example with 10, 20, 10, 20, 10.... which has the 50% and leads to a correlation of 0,00. So as long as there is no "jump" but still a constant development, there will be this "50% rule".

Answer (score 2):

The correlation coefficient measures the strength of *linear relation* between two variables.

The closer the correlation is to plus-one or minus-one the stronger the linear relationship.   A correlation coefficient of exactly plus-one means there is a perfect, direct, *increasing* linear-relation.   A correlation coefficient of exactly minus-one means that there is a perfect, direct, *decreasing* linear relation.

A correlation of zero means there is no linear relation.   Note that this does not exclude the possibility of a *non-linear* relationship.

---

I am not sure how those percentages might be derived.   However, a correlation coefficient of one means that increasing one variable always increases the other by some fixed proportion, and a correlation coefficient of *minus one* means increasing one variable always *decreases* the other by some fixed proportion.

However, while a correlation coefficient of zero *could* mean that the two variables are independent, it *need* not.   They could be related in a non-linear way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think a derivation of percentages makes sense at all?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @MareInfinitus [That](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linearregression+(1,1),+(2,2),+(3,3),+(4,4),+(5,5),+(6,6),+(7,5),+(8,4),+(9,3),+(10,2),+(11,1)) is an example of a non-linear relation.  There are two regions where the variables appear to have a perfect direct relation - one increasing, one decreasing - but they are uncorrelated over the entire support.

Comment: Does this say that one cancels out the other, so that the 50 percent statement is correct as long as the factor of movement is constant? If a "jump" is made such as 10 20 30 40 50 *30* 20 10 there is no 0,00 correlation coefficient.